# How to set the height and width of the CDockable pane

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, sdi

I want to set the height and the width of the dockable panes. I tried passing the value in the CRect parameter to the OnCreate function but that didnt work. can anybody help in resolving this

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get the effect you want by calling `SetWindowPos(... SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE)`, this will work in the case the pane is undocked.

I don't know if the result will constructive at all when the pane is docked or hidden. You can also add handlers for WM_SIZING and WM_SIZE in your CDockablePane derived class to limit the size of the pane within a desired range.

MFC manages the pane sizes and uses values stored in the registry.  That is a real pain, especially when a pane disappears in a new version of your software.  I don't know of an *easy* way to turn this off.  But it can be done.